# Configurations which we can do to allow the Use Of Managed Identity for AzureCognitiveSearchChatExtensionConfiguration Class

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

Hi was just looking at the document's and found that for using the AzureCognitiveSearchChatExtensionConfiguration Class we need to pass on search key and endpoint. But how can we utilize the Azure Managed Identity on it.

I have tried with key vault.
But need some assistance with utilizing this with the Managed Identity.
Ref :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.openai.azurecognitivesearchchatextensionconfiguration?view=azure-dotnet-preview

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to avoid passing the search key and use managed identities for permissions.

As stated in the documentation you mentioned, "If not otherwise provided, On Your Data will attempt to use System Managed Identity (default credential) authentication.". So all you have to do is:

- do not pass a search key
- enable System Identity on your Azure OpenAI resource (as it is the resource which will call your Azure AI Search)
- add an RBAC permission on your Search resource, enabling the identity of your Azure OpenAI resource (that you enabled previously) to query data. A "Search Index Data Reader" permission (role definition ID 1407120a-92aa-4202-b7e9-c0e197c71c8f) should be sufficiant

Comment: Hi @Nicolas R have solved my initial question but now i am getting the error for vector embedding as below. 
'embeddingKey' is a required parameter for the AzureCognitiveSearch data source type. This parameter is required for queryType vectorSemanticHybrid.

Comment: While implementing this i am getting this error.
Please help me out in understanding this error.
{"error": {"requestid": "c8fc4fcd-7986-4d4d-9753-ac25d2d5d9281029ue", "code": 400, "message": "Invalid AzureCognitiveSearch configuration detected: Call to get ACS index failed. Check you are using correct index, instance and api_key.\n"}}

Comment: Looks like an authentication issue. How are you calling the service?